# Why can't I load angular-cookies into my app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am trying to fix this problem, but I can't get it to work. I want to include the `NgCookies` *(angular-cookies)* into my app, but it's just giving me an error.

I have this:

**Including the JS:**

```
<html>
    <script src="js/angular1.6.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-cookies.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Application controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ui.router', 'ngCordova', 'ngCookies']);
```

**The controller:**

```
myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$cookies', function ($scope, $cookies) {
    // Retrieving a cookie
  $scope.userName = $cookies.userName || "";

  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.userName = 'testUser';
}]);
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookiesProvider <- $cookies <- HomeController
```

I am using Angular version **1.6.1** and Angular-Cookies version **1.6.1**

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I checked other questions, but the solutions given there are not working for me. I checked the versions, I checked if I include Angular before Angular-Cookies etcetera. I am out of options now.

Comment: Do you have any other console errors ?

Comment: Nope, that's all I have.. it's just crazy. No idea what happens here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as expected if you included the same version of angular and angular-cookie as in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mvf83mvL2F7BPpR6ZtWI?p=preview).

I see that you are injecting `ngCordova` and i believe that you are using ionic framework in your development. By default, Ionic comes bundle with angularJS and there is no need to include additional `angular.js` script on top of ionic and you should avoid doing so as it could lead to unexpected break.

I would suggest you to check the angular version that comes bundle with the ionic version you are using and include the same version of `angular-cookies` with the angular version that comes bundle with ionic.

Comment: I read that Ionic and angular-cookies is a no-go. That's why I'll just try to use localstorage instead. Thanks whyyie.